# Notepad++ Multiline selection based on character length

Tags: notepad++

Naturally with NP++ as with any text field I can
hold SHIFT and press direction keys to select whole words or sentences.

How could I perform some keyboardfu and select say "Naturally with NP++" on one line and "hold SHIFT and press" on the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what you are asking.. If its block-select then you can hold shift and alt to select blocks.